# Slot Machine Patterns

Tags: probability

Imagine a slot machine with $4$ identical reels and $4$ symbols on each reel, when the slots are spun the result **must** match one of the following $5$ patterns of matching symbols.

> 2 matching symbols
>
> 2 pairs of matching symbols
>
> 3 matching symbols
>
> 4 matching symbols
>
> no matching symbols

Therefore when $R = 4$ and $S = 4$ the number of patterns is $5$.

Is there a way to generalise the number of possible patterns to a machine with $R$ reels and $S$ symbols on each reel? E.g. when $R = 4$ and $S = 3$ the number of patterns is $4$.

Some more examples of small values of $R$ and $S$ can be found in the spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HlH1Uctj98ZedPptf-82emUeDVDbCFaEP1bKBUhXuxk/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Are you looking for the probabilities of each or are you looking for the possible break-downs in terms of what patterns are possible?  Are all of the symbols on each reel different?  Are the sets of symbols the same on each reel?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Please edit the question to show us how you can get started. What are the  possible patterns for some small values of $R$ and $S$.

Comment: This is an interesting combinatorial question. There's probably a recursive way to count the number of patterns - that is, a way to find the number for $R$ and $S$ in terms of the numbers for smaller values. There may be a formula (somewhat less likely). Please edit the question to tell us something about why you want to know, and how large $R$ and $S$ might be. Do you need this for something else, or is it just plain curiousity? Would a recursion you could implement in a program be useful?

Comment: This seems like a Multinomial distribution question. Check out http://www.randomservices.org/random/bernoulli/Multinomial.html Although it seems like this may be a partition of a set so maybe try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: @TonyHellmuth Thanks for your help, looking into partitions I have realised that when **R** and **S** are equal the number of patterns is the number of partitions of **S** (or **R**).

Comment: Perhaps there is a neat trick using compositions? It isn't super light, but perhaps you can get a closed form using it: https://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/14-5/abramson.pdf